# Firefox's spellchecker (typo-checker?) doesn't catch repeated repeated words

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Are there any addons/extensions for Firefox that do?

**Edit**

Okay, technically, repeated words are not "bad spelling", so I massaged the title of this question a bit. Hopefully, that will appease you semantic types a little :)

Comment: Spellchecking is not the same as as grammarchecking. ;)  Thank you, by the way, for the irony in "Are the any..." :-D

Comment: Accidental irony -- fixed :)

Comment: Okay, you broke me down. New title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Firefox does not do grammar checking. Only incorrectly typed words.

Don't think there is an add-on that does that though.

Comment: Imagine the memory overhead if it did :O

Comment: @John, true for a full grammarchecker, but just checking for repeated words would have very low overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a grammer checker add-on available for firefox.  I've not used but I plan to:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/after-the-deadline-spell-and-g/